# forward geocoding completionHandler is not executing in iOS swift4

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, geocoding, cllocation

I am trying convert to addresses into latlongs to place them on googleMap but, when I pass the address String to `geoCoder.geoAddressString(fullAddress)` and running application, completionHandler is not executing, I tried with breakpoint at `geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(fullAddress) { (placemarks, error)` and when I click on stepover it is coming out if the completionHandler..

Now, I have no idea why this is happening... Does anyone know? please Help..

see My code Here:

```
 func loadMarkers() {

        for i in 0..<self.professioanlDetailsAH.count {

            let fullAddress = "\(self.professioanlDetailsAH[i]["searchAddress"]!)"

            if !fullAddress.isEmpty {
                var geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(fullAddress) { (placemarks, error) in
                            guard
                                let placemarks = placemarks,
                                let addressLocation = placemarks.first?.location
                                else {
                                    // handle no location found
                                    return
                            }

                            let latitude = addressLocation.coordinate.latitude
                            let longitude = addressLocation.coordinate.longitude
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:

```
func loadMarkers() {
        for i in 0..<self.professioanlDetailsAH.count {

            print(self.professioanlDetailsAH[i]["firstName"]!)

            let fullAddress = "\(self.professioanlDetailsAH[i]["searchAddress"]!)"

            print(fullAddress)

            if !fullAddress.isEmpty {
            geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(fullAddress) {(placemarks, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    print(error!)
                }

                else{
                guard
                        let placemarks = placemarks,
                        let addressLocation = placemarks.first?.location
                else {return}

                            let latitude = addressLocation.coordinate.latitude
                            let longitude = addressLocation.coordinate.longitude

                print("lat:\(latitude), long:\(longitude)")

                }
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Place your breakpoint inside your completion handler. `geoCodeAddressString` is asynchronous call, it will return immediately. Also check the error and print it if it is not nil.

Comment: @Badhan Ganesh Thanks for the reply, Please see my edit and it lt is call the geoCoder after the completion of the loop and hence I am getting the lat long of last address that passed in the loop. But, I want pass all the address in the loop. How to do that???

Comment: Where do you add your marker in map?? The `geocodeAddressString` in the for loop will return for each iteration, but it might take some time.